# Match two sheets to find differences

Tags: sql, excel, excel-formula, vba

I have one document (two sheets) that I am trying to compare between.  I have cleaned up the columns so both have our unique reference number in column A, the vendor expense in column B and the revenue in column C. I am trying to do an internal audit of sorts without going through every one individually.

One sheet contains data from two years whereas the other contains data from one year.  It is not a definitive date so I didn't want to remove any.

[Accountants Export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EzCJ.png)[image: Accountants Export]
[My Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNfhD.png)[image: My Data]

How would I go about matching the unique identifier in column A and highlighting if there is a difference in the information in column B or C?

Comment: Did you try using vlookups?

Comment: I tried, I am not great with excel.  Is there anyway you could walk me through it or explicitly state how to do it?  Thanks Scott

Answer (score 0):

here is the code to do it in VBA

I suppose for both `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` that:

`ColumnA` is "Pro", `ColumnB` Gross Rate and `ColumnC` "Carrier Exp"
All headers are in `Row1` and the data starts in `row2`

Here is the code:

```
Sub test()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim Lastrow As Long, Lastrow2 As Long
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")

Lastrow = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Lastrow2 = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


For i = 2 To Lastrow


    For j = 2 To Lastrow2


        If ws1.Range("A" & i).Value = ws2.Range("A" & j).Value Then


            If Not ws1.Range("B" & i).Value = ws2.Range("B" & j).Value Then

               ws1.Range("B" & i).Interior.Color = vbYellow
               ws2.Range("B" & j).Interior.Color = vbYellow

            End If

            If Not ws1.Range("C" & i).Value = ws2.Range("C" & j).Value Then

             ws1.Range("C" & i).Interior.Color = vbYellow
             ws2.Range("C" & j).Interior.Color = vbYellow

            End If

        End If

    Next j

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you!  I will try this now.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: I ran it, so far looks exactly what I was looking for.  Quick question:  does this highlight if both the Revenue don't match OR the Carrier Expense don't match?

Comment: If there is only the revenue that doesn't match so only the revenue will be highlighted. If only the carrier Expense doesn't match so it will be highlighted. If both dont match bot will be highlighted.